# Declare type of function in a function

Tags: function, haskell, types

I have two functions:

```
prop_merge_check :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prop_merge_check xs ys = length (merge xs ys) == length (sort (xs ++ ys))

prop_unzip_check :: Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
prop_unzip_check xs = length (unzip xs) >= 0
```

How can I declare the types of function in a function itself?

I tried this way, but it didn't work out for me.

```
prop_merge_check xs ys = length (merge (xs::[a]) (ys::[a])) 
                           == length (sort ( (xs::[a]) ++ (ys::[a]) ))

prop_unzip_check xs = length (unzip (xs::[(a,b)])) >= 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a side-effect of Haskell's implicit forall's. Haskell automatically adds 'forall's to all type signatures as necessary, these act as "scoping" rules which limit the names to a particular area. Haskell interprets your signature as:

```
prop_merge_check :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prop_merge_check xs ys =
    length (merge (xs::forall a. [a]) (ys:: forall a. [a])) == (length (sort ((xs:: forall a. [a]) ++ (ys:: forall a. [a]))))
```

That is; it sees every `a` in every signature as a completely different variable! That's why it can't make the types work properly. This is an annoying and unobvious quirk, but there's a way around it.

If we enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` and provide an *explicit* forall in the type signature we tell Haskell that we want the scope of the type variables to span the whole function body:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
-- ^ Put that at the top of your module

prop_merge_check :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prop_merge_check xs ys =
    length (merge (xs::[a]) (ys::[a])) == (length (sort ((xs::[a]) ++ (ys::[a]))))
```

This version should compile, because now the `a` in all signatures is considered the *same*. We can quantify more than one type variable at a time:

```
prop_unzip_check :: forall a b. Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
prop_unzip_check xs = length (unzip (xs::[(a,b)])) >= 0
```

Unfortunately there's not currently an easy way to do this sort of thing without adding the explicit forall in the top-level signature, but there are a few proposals for changes to this behaviour. They likely won't be coming any time soon though; so I wouldn't hold your breath.

Good luck! You can look up the docs on ScopedTypeVariables and ExistentialQuantification to learn more about this quirk.

Comment: We can quantify multiple variables at a time; I added that solution to my answer now as well.

Comment: deleted previous comment by a mistake ;c

Comment: but I am still receiving one kind of error from compiler, I am going to create another question, will you take a look please ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any other questions from you at the moment; are you sure you submitted it?

Comment: it says only one post per 1.30h is alowed, so im waiting :c . maybe i can somehow write directly to you here? im really new in here

Comment: If it's really a different topic, best to just wait it out. You can ping me in the comments here when it's up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202993/discussion-between-osobennyj-and-chris-penner).

Comment: Now you can check it out!